# Using turf.js in Cordova project doesn't work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, turfjs

I am trying to create a dot density map visualization in my cordova ionic mobile application and I am failing to load turf.min.js.

I included it in the index.html file as:

`<script src="js/libs/turf.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

As soon as the app loads, I can see this error in the console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name**

The turf object comes out to be undefined where I am using it in code.

I am stuck badly at this, please help!!

Comment: Usinfg the unminified turf.js does not give an error and it works well. But the issue with the minified version still prevails.